# Subclass NSView to change background color

Tags: cocoa

I want to change the background color of a custom view. I have a subclass NSView something like that:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface CustomBGView : NSView {
NSColor myColor; 
} @end
```

and the .m

```
  @implementation CustomBGView

  - (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
  {
    [myColor set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
  }

  - (void)changeColor:(NSColor*) aColor
 {
    myColor = aColor;
 }
```

The changeColor method is for change color in the app controller. I also define a IBOutlet for the custom view called myView binded in IB.

The problem is when I use changeColor in the app controller like this:

```
[myView changeColor: [NSColor colorWithCalibratedRed:0.5 green:0.5 blue:0.5 alpha:1.0]];
```

There is a 'Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”. If I use instead something like this:

```
[myView changeColor: [NSColor whiteColor]];
```

works fine.

Where is the Problem? Thanks in advance

---

Thanks Chuck! Now with "retain" works fine.

And why it works without retain in one case ([myView changeColor: [NSColor whiteColor]];) and not in the other???

Comment: [NSColor whiteColor] is some kind of comstant. It's quasi a singleton. So it doesn't get released. And so it doesn't break.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're storing the argument to `changeColor:` in an instance variable, but not retaining it, so you don't own it and it thinks it can go away.