# cocoa objective-c: Change background color of custom view

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, colors, background, nsview

If I have a bunch of custom views that I made in IB, how can I set up a background color for each when the app awakesFromNib?

Comment: I've you've made the views in Interface Builder, why not just set the required background colo(u)r there?

Comment: A quick search on Stack Overflow yields two equivalent questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2962790/best-way-to-change-the-background-color-for-an-nsview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781326/subclass-nsview-to-change-background-color

Comment: @Bavarious Hmm... neither of those questions are particularly epic (or usefully generic) it has to be said.

Comment: @middaparka Be that as it may, a good question would have referred to those two questions had the OP done his homework. ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your NSView subclass:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)aRect
{
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    NSRectFill([self bounds]);
}
```