# How to use the Colors window in my OS X app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm writing an app, where I'd like to change the fill color of a rectangle by setting new color in the Colors window:

[image]

When my app is running, I can show this window by pressing ⌘⇧C. I want to connect that window with my ViewController, get the new color that user selected, and use it as the fill color for my NSRect in the `drawRect:` method.

How can I set and get colors from the Colors window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to use is the `NSColorPicker` class. Documentation starts [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/ChoosingColors.html).

The code in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781326/subclass-nsview-to-change-background-color) shows the direction you need to go in. You need to implement the `changeColor:` method in your first responder. (Don't follow that code exactly because it has a bug.)

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for! I wish I could vote your answer up.

Comment: It has been a while since I've used these APIs, but `NSColorPanel` gives you access to the `NSColorPicker` and vice versa.