# Ios select color using color wheel

Tags: objective-c, macos, uicolor

I have seen numerous post about making your own "color selector", which I'm currently work on. But I came across one of apple (objective c) sample code: [Circle view](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/CircleView/Introduction/Intro.html). Circleview have a color selector, which seem to have been supply by apple (Like a UIButton). This is what it look like:

[image: CircleView]

On runtime, it has this rectangular button where when you press it, a circle selector pop up:

[image: CircleView With Color]

Changing color:

[image: Circle View Change Color]

I was wondering if the color selector was made (by apple, for users to have access to) or was it made by the programmer (who made circle view). If it was made by the programmer, does anyone have any idea on how he or she made it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSColorWell` for this purpose. For doing this follow these steps.

1. create an IBAction in your code like

`- (IBAction)useColorFromWell:(NSColorWell *)sender{
   //Use [sender color] for color. 
}`

2. Drag and drop an `NSColorWell` object to your xib/storyboard.
3. Connect `NSColorWell`'s action to the IBAction you created.

Run your app :)

**UPDATE**

See the gif for easy understanding
[image]

Comment: Is there any "Color Well" Object in IOS development?

Comment: No, that is for mac. Your question was unclear that needs iOS component for this. You can find some libraries here https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=color%20picker

Answer (score 1):

It is a system provided component. Have a look at *Colorwell* / *ColorPanel* [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DrawColor/Tasks/ChoosingColors.html). and the [`NSColorwell` Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSColorWell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSColorWell/activate:)

Also have a look at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3781326/subclass-nsview-to-change-background-color).